# Calling multiple PHP functions - best practice

Tags: php

I have an image upload form with which I call multiple functions before uploading the file such as checking the size, dimensions and that it is a valid image. The code works but calling the functions and dealing with the results seems quite cumbersome and complex.

Is there a tidier way of structuring the code.

This is what I currently have:

```
if(checkvalidfile("img",$ext)){
    if(checksize($size, 524288)) {
        if(checkdimensions($tmp, 300)) {
            $newfilename = renamefile($ext);
            uploadfile($tmp, $bucket, "user_docs/agency_".$agency_id."/brand_logos/", $newfilename, $s3);
            header('Location: ./message.php?action=newlogo'); 
        } else {
        echo "Your image can't be bigger than 300 x 300px";
        die;
        }
    } else {
    echo "File size is too big!";
    die;
    }
} else {
echo "Not a valid file";
die;
}
```

Comment: Off-topic here. Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: this is more appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a code review request. This is better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com


Comment: Exceptions work great for this type of error handling. (`try` / `throw` / `catch`)

Comment: I didn't even know about codereview. Thanks for the heads-up. I'll post it on there instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to `else` since you're `die`ing. Negate your conditions with `!` and unnest them all:

```
if(!checkvalidfile("img",$ext)){
  echo "Error message";
  die;
}

if(!checksize($size, 524288)) {
  echo "error message";
  die;
}

if(!checkdimensions($tmp, 300)) {
  echo "Error message";
  die;
}

$newfilename = renamefile($ext);
uploadfile($tmp, $bucket, "user_docs/agency_".$agency_id."/brand_logos/", $newfilename, $s3);
header('Location: ./message.php?action=newlogo');
```

If you decide that `die` isn't the correct thing to do (it's definitely not, that's a pretty bad user experience) then you can put your conditions in a single function which returns an error message on failure, or `false` on success:

```
function checkValid() {
  if(!checkvalidfile("img",$ext)
    return "Error message 1";

  if(!checksize($size, 524288))
    return "error message 2";

  if(!checkdimensions($tmp, 300))
    return "error message 3";

  return false;
}


if ($error = checkValid()) {
  echo $error;
} else {

  $newfilename = renamefile($ext);
  uploadfile($tmp, $bucket, "user_docs/agency_".$agency_id."/brand_logos/", $newfilename, $s3);
  header('Location: ./message.php?action=newlogo'); 
}
```